# DECLARE xml and then INSERT INTO table

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I have a application thas sends an xml into my db2 stored procedure
In SQL Server the stored procedure is written like this:

```
DECLARE @startWithDiagnosisNumbers  xml
SELECT @startWithDiagnosisNumbers = N'<Ids><id>G43</id><id>G44</id></Ids>'

DECLARE @TEMP_CXP_DiagnosisNumbers TABLE (ID nvarchar(50)) 
INSERT INTO @TEMP_CXP_DiagnosisNumbers (ID) 
SELECT ParamValues.ID.value('.','NVARCHAR(50)')
FROM @startWithDiagnosisNumbers .nodes('/Ids/id') as ParamValues(ID)
```

How do I translate this over to db2?
I have tried this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE startWithDiagnosisNumbers XML;
END
```

but get error message: "The data type for parameter or SQL variable"STARTWITHDIAGNOSISNUMBERS" is not supported in the  routine, compound SQL statement, or parameter list of a cursor value constructor."

And I cant find how to translate the INSERT INTO.

I am very grateful for any help :-)

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: db2 ver 9.7 
plattform windows

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations on the use of XML data type, as [described in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00789n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-1-141&lang=en).  Make sure you have the latest fix pack for your version and try to write your code as a stored procedure instead of a simple compound SQL statement (a.k.a. anonymous block).

To extract data from the XML document in a table form you can use the [XMLTABLE function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022195.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-3-2&lang=en) -- check examples in the manual.

PS. Using SQL Server-centric approaches such as extensive use of temporary tables isn't necessarily the most efficient way of accomplish things in DB2.